# Provide different JS behaviour before user interactions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

My ASP.NET MVC 3 site generates and html with scripts around my input fields, to provide a cascading dropdown functionality.

For example, in my html I have a script call like this:

```
$ae.ajaxDropdown(
```

`$ae` is defined in a separate .js file. My problem is that I need some jQuery `parent.change` subscriptions not to work until a user has actually stareted interacting with the page and by doing this - invoked jquery routines on html elements.

If we could have used C# on the client, I would just use a `bool isBeforeInteraction` variable, that I would set to `true` at the beggining of the javascript parsing and execution, and would have set to `false` when the user has actually started elements manipulations. My jquery .change subscriptions would then work.

Is there a similar way to filter js code (that is in a separate .js file) based on a "page-wide" boolean variable?

Comment: could you not set a live event on something that would be interacted with and then call the code to enable the rest of your code like you say by setting a global variable to true, and your code only running if value IS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the keydown event as follows:

```
var isBeforeInteraction = true;
$(document).bind('keydown',
  function(evt) {
    if (isBeforeInteraction) {
      alert ('First User Interaction');
      isBeforeInteraction = false;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I think `bind()` is dreprecated as of jQ 1.7+ in favor of `on()`

Comment: @ron, thanks, I almost got it to work, but it seems like 'keydown' is triggered when the keyboard button is pressed with page focused. How can I subscribe to both keyboard and mouse interactions?

Comment: I went ahead an subscribed to both 'keydown' and 'mousedown' events. And then unsubscribed.